# res->getString(1) mysql connector crash debug

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a problem when i use mysql connector c++ and visual studio on the debug mode. It compiles just fine. My algorithm works on release mode. When i switch to debug mode, he complies but he crash while running. 
I believe that he crash each time i use res->getString() . 
I m using visual studio 2013, mysql connector.C++ 1.1 . I already added the dependencies

- C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\lib\debug
- C:\Program Files\Boost SDK;
- C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\include
- mysqlcppconn.lib  and mysqlcppconn.dll
- CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC= ;HAVE_INT8_T=1 ( on the processor definition)
- run time library : /MDd ( it the only think that works )
  I copied mysqlcppconn.lib  and mysqlcppconn.dll  in the debug directory of my project

with this configuration my programm works on release mode ( changing Connector.C++ 1.1\lib\debug to Connector.C++ 1.1\lib\opt ).

In the debug mode, he says Debug Assertion failed :

- File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgheap.c
- Line 1322
- Expression : _CrtIsValidHeapPointer( pUserData)
- Press Rety to debug the application 
  then i had to choose one buttom ( Ignore; Restart ; leave ). When i press Ignore he continue to run i have the first results but he crashs again

This is my code section

{

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
/* MySQL Connector/C++ specific headers */
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/connection.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/metadata.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset_metadata.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/warning.h>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace sql;

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{

     const char*                    str_DataBaseMarketData_Server = "root";

      const char*                   str_DataBaseMarketData_User = "root";
      const char*                   str_DataBaseMarketData_Password ="root";
      const char*                   str_DataBaseMarketData_Database ="bd test";

    cout << "Connector/C++ tutorial framework..." << endl;
    cout << endl;

    string fld;
    try {
        sql::Driver* driver = get_driver_instance();
        std::auto_ptr<sql::Connection> con(driver->connect(str_DataBaseMarketData_Server, str_DataBaseMarketData_User, str_DataBaseMarketData_Password));
        con->setSchema(str_DataBaseMarketData_Database);
        std::auto_ptr<sql::Statement> stmt(con->createStatement());

        sql::SQLString *data = new SQLString();
        std::auto_ptr<sql::ResultSet> res(stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM news "));
        //ResultSetMetaData *res_meta = res->getMetaData();
        //cout << res_meta->getColumnDisplaySize( 1) << endl << endl;
        while (res->next()){

            fld = res->getString(2).c_str();
        }
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        /*
        The MySQL Connector/C++ throws three different exceptions:

        - sql::MethodNotImplementedException (derived from sql::SQLException)
        - sql::InvalidArgumentException (derived from sql::SQLException)
        - sql::SQLException (derived from std::runtime_error)
        */
        cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
        /* Use what() (derived from std::runtime_error) to fetch the error message */
        cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cout << "Done." << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

}

This things turns me crazy because when i replace getString() by anything else, it works sweetly.Could you help me please ? 
I m running under a 32 bit.

Comment: What is your schema? Are there two columns? Is the second a string?

Comment: My table is composed by 2 colonne ( "id" : int ; the second colonne "title" : varchar(256) )